# Centos 7- flask Give permissions to see bash history from other users

Tags: python, linux, bash, centos7

I defined a function that return the last commands from an specific user. This is the code:

```
def user_commands(user):
    line = "/home/"+user+"/.bash_history"
    commands = Popen([ "tail", line], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
    return commands
```

But it only works with my user python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqImK.png)

If i use another user it doesnt show me the list of commands.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuTqD.png)

I think is because it need permissions to see the bash_history from other users. What can i do if i want it to work with all users.

Comment: Could you post the errors you get, what you expect, what actually happens, how they differ, etc in text rather than blurry offsite links?

Comment: @pvg  I am working with flask and i want to create a script that show me the list of commands from a specific user. My problem is that it only works from one user: python, that is the actual user when i run my python script. If i put in my browser another user, like in this example with the user root http://192.168.56.101:8080/v1.0/users/root/commands it doesnt appear any command. I expect that the browser show me the list of commands from the user root as it works for python. I need to access the bash_history from other users an then show its commands in the browser using my script with flask

Comment: Any additional details should be edited into your question. Please add them there.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue. Make sure the user the script is running as has permissions to access the bash history file.

The quick and dirty answer is to run the script as root.

A better idea might be running a cron job to gather the info you need and place it in a directory accessible by the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it was a permissions issue, i solved adding this commands:

```
chown -R python /home
chown -R u+rX /home
```

Comment: That seems like a giant security hole.